# Optimal Betting Strategy in Coin Toss

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization, gambling

#### Goal:

Participate in a coin-tossing game with the aim to maximize your earnings. A fundamental part of the game is formulating a strategy that optimizes your earnings based on the observation of the coin toss outcomes.

#### Rules:

1. **The Coin**:

   - A coin is tossed, landing on "HEADS" with an unknown probability  p .
2. **Observation and Betting**:

   - You have the option to either observe the outcome of the toss without betting or place a fixed bet on an interval where you believe  p  lies.
3. **Placing Bets**:

   - Betting involves selecting a confidence interval where you believe the probability  p exists.
   - The bet is fixed, meaning you bet the same amount each time.
4. **Earnings**:

   - If you choose an interval that includes p , you earn a point.
   - If you narrow down the interval size compared to the previous round while  p  is still within the interval, your earnings are quadratically increased based on the reduction in the interval size.
5. **Strategy**:

   - The goal of the game is to find the best strategy that maximizes your total earnings.
   - The strategy involves when to observe, when to bet, and how to adjust the betting intervals based on the observed outcomes.

#### Gameplay:

- In each round, the game simulates a coin toss, revealing whether it lands on "HEADS" or "TAILS".
- Based on the outcomes, you make a decision—either to observe or to bet by choosing a probability interval.
- Implement your strategy based on the observations to optimize the betting intervals and maximize earnings.

#### Conclusion of the Game:

- The game proceeds for a set number of rounds (e.g., 100 rounds).
- At the end of the game, the actual value of  p is disclosed, and your total earnings are calculated, showcasing the effectiveness of your strategy.

#### Example:

- For instance, you decide to observe for the first five rounds, noting the outcomes.
- In the subsequent round, you may choose to bet with a certain interval based on your observations and strategy.
- Continually adjust your strategy based on the outcomes and the objective to find the most profitable betting intervals.

Remember, the fundamental aim is to develop and apply a strategy that maximally increases your earnings throughout the game, using observation and intelligent betting based on the revealed outcomes.

Comment: In the round you bet, do you see the outcome?

Comment: Yes, you see if you win or loose so at the end of each round, you know if p is your interval or not.

Comment: Why would you ever observe without betting - surely you would be bound to win something if you chose the interval $p \in [0, 1]$